# Can't focus searchBar in searchController in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchcontroller

like in topic - I can't focus searchBar despite that i set this delegate and active.
Here is my code from viewdidLoad():

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.delegate = self as? UISearchControllerDelegate
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.isActive = true
    self.definesPresentationContext = false
    let newSearchBar = searchController.searchBar
```

Also Ive set `var searchBar: UISearchBar!` and `searchBar = newSearchBar`

and it's look like that in app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL6ds.png

Anyway, when I click in this searchbar then click TAB on my keyboard then im able to write something...

Comment: Can someone help???

Comment: Can someone help me?? :(